# Calculating individual mean from a sum of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose that I have $X_1, X_2, X_3$ as a sequence of independent random variables with $E(X_i)<+\infty$ but not identically distributed, so they have different $E(X_1)\neq E(X_2)\neq E(X_3)$. Let's say that $P(n)=E(X_1^n)+E(X_2^n)+E(X_3^n)$ is available for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but not the individual $E(X_i)$. How can I calculate each $E(X_i)$ using $P(n)$?

Comment: That is absolutely correct! Sorry, I just put the wrong problem. The random variables are in fact not identically distributed.

Comment: Do we know $P(n) < \infty$ for all $n$?

Comment: I think I can say that $E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_3) = 1$ and $E(X_1^n)+E(X_2^n)+E(X_3^n) < 1$. This is what I know.

Comment: It'll be hard.  The given $P(n)$ pose an instance of the "moment problem" for the mixture of the distributions of the 3 $X_i$ variables.  Even if that problem has a unique solution, your individual $X_i$'s distributions are only constrained to some convex set of possibilities.  Without further constraints I think your question is not practically answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my restatement of the problem, incorporating material from the OP's comments.

We are told there exist  three probability measures $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ on the reals, are  given the values of $P(n)=\sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{\mathbb R} x^n \alpha_i(dx)$, for $n=1,2,\ldots$, and are told that $P(1)=1$ and $P(n)<1$ for $n>1$.  Further, no two of the  $\alpha_i$ are equal.

Note that  $\alpha_1$ is not uniquely determined by this data: if $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ satisfy the conditions, so do $(\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_1)$, and $((\alpha_1+\alpha_2)/2,(\alpha_2+\alpha_3)/2,
(\alpha_3+\alpha_1)/2)$, and so on.

The question is: do these data imply any bounds on $\int_{\mathbb R} x \alpha_1(dx)$, and if so, how can we calculate them?

An answer is, yes, theoretically, there is a maximal closed interval $[R,S]$ such that for any $a\in [R,S]$ we have $\int_{\mathbb R} x \alpha_1(dx)=a$ for some choice of the $\alpha_i$ consistent with given $P(n)$ sequence.  What follows is
an outline of why: a sketch of a proof and of a calculation.
(Unfortunately, the calculation is probably feasible only in contrived special cases.)

Let $\mu=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3$, so  $P(n)$ is the $n$-th moment of $\mu$.  Since $P(n)$ is bounded, $\mu$ has bounded support (in fact, contained in $[-1,1]$), and $\mu$ is uniquely determined by the moment sequence $P(n)$ by an instance of the
[Hausdorff moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem). In theory, we "know" $\mu$. Since $\alpha_i\ll \mu$ we can, by the Radon-Nikodym theorem, write $\alpha_i(dx)=A_i(x)\mu(dx)$, where the functions $A_i$ are the RN derivatives $$A_i(x)=\frac{d\alpha_i}{d\mu}.$$  So far we don't know the $\alpha_i$ and don't know the $A_i(x)$ but do know that $\sum A_i(x)=1$ and  $0\le A_i(x)\le 1$ for $\mu$-almost all $x$, and that $\int_{\mathbb R}A_i(x)\mu(dx)=1$.

Now consider the problem of minimizing $\phi(A)=\int_{\mathbb R}xA(x)\mu(dx)$ subject to the constraints $0\le A(x)\le 1$ and $\int_{\mathbb R}A(x)\mu(dx)=1$. The [Neyman-Pearson lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%occurs80%93Pearson_lemma)
tells us that the minimum is attained, by a function of form
$$A(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x<x_0\\c&x=x_0\\0&x>x_0\end{cases}$$
for some $x_0$ and $c$, with $c\in[0,1]$.
The sought-for $R$ is the value of the integral $\phi(A)$.  The $S$ is given by maximizing $\phi$ subject to the same constraints; the maximizer has form$$A(x)=\begin{cases}0& x<x_0\\c&x=x_0\\1&x>x_0\end{cases}$$
for some other $x_0$ and $c$, with $c\in[0,1]$.
One can exhibit $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ by taking $A_1$ to minimize $\phi$, by taking $A_3$ to maximize $\phi$, and then taking $A_2=1-(A_1+A_3)$, and then building $\alpha_i=A_i\mu$.

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thanks! Does this solution work for more than 3 random variables?

Comment: Furthermore, should $A_2 = 3 - (A_1 + A_3)$?

Comment: The cleanup formula for $A_2$ was wrong; thanks for the catch!  This approach will work for more than 3 random variables.  Do you have some example in mind?

Comment: I was thinking about making the problem more generic such that $P(n)=X_1^n+X_2^n+...+X_k^n+$. You already described the solution for k=3, but it would be more interesting make it for k=4, 5, 6...

Comment: Furthermore, I need to spend more time studying the topic of probability measures. I am having difficulties to understand the math notation. But, I need to thank you for helping me on this !!

Comment: Shouldn't it be  (in fact, contained in [0,1])?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what "it" means in your most recent comment.  I think my $R$ and $S$ must obey $|R|,|S|\le 1$ but I don't see anything ruling out values in $[-1,0)$.